# python scripts for accessing info from a postgresql database in case of a qgis application?

Tags: qgis, python, postgresql

I am beginner and I need to know if I could access a postgresql database from python script made for a qgis application

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can,

Take a look at [this example](http://pyqgis.com/blog/2013/04/11/creating-a-postgresql-connection-from-a-qgis-layer-datasource/) and at the [pyqgis developper cookbook examples](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers).